# Convert char array from message queue to int array

Tags: c

So i get a message from message queue, and it should look like this eg: (3 2 1)
I need to convert this 3 element and store in an integer array.

```
do
{
  if(message.mesg_text[x]!=' ')
  {
    asd[j]=(int)message.mesg_text[x]-48;
    x++;
  }
  else
  {
    j++;
    x++;
  }
}while(message.mesg_text!='\0');
```

Comment: `asd[j]=(int)message.mesg_text[x];` -> `asd[j] = message.mesg_text[x] - '0';` probably.

Comment: it doesn't work. It converts well the first 2, but at the last one i get negative value

Comment: In your `if` block, you increment `j` in the `else`. But, I think that's reversed. You want the `j++` in the `if` part and _not_ the `else` part

Comment: thanks :D that solved.

Comment: Glad that fixed it. But, your 2nd edit looks like it broke the `while`. How about something like: `while (j < 3) { int chr = message.mesg_text[x++]; if (chr == 0) break; if (chr != ' ') asd[j++] = chr - '0'; }`

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you want to extract numbers from a list stored/provided as a string, e.g. "(1 2 3)".

Note that C provides atoi(3) to convert string representation of interger to int type.
Also note that C provides ctype.h which provides isdigit() and isspace() to determine whether a character is a number or blank space.
Extra spaces can be stripped by skipping over spaces...

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strtok.h>

int
list_extract_ints(char* msg, int asd[], int capacity) {
    // weakest precondition(s):
    // message needs to be valid string
    if( ! msg ) { return 0; }
    if( capacity <= 0 ) { return 0; }

    int count = 0;
    char* p = msg;

    int len = strlen(p);
    // skip leading space
    for( ; *p && isspace(*p); ) { p++; }
    // strip trailing blanks?
    // skip '('
    if( '(' == *p ) { p++; }
    char ptoken = strtok(p," ");
    // do you allow '+' or '-'?
    if( ptoken && isdigit(*ptoken) ) {
        // may want to skip spaces here...
        asd[count++] = atoi(ptoken);
    }
    // gather ints until capacity reached, or list end
    for( ; (count<capacity) && (ptoken = strtok(NULL, " )")); ) {
        // may want to skip spaces here...
        if( ptoken && isdigit(*ptoken) ) {
            asd[count++] = atoi(ptoken);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Then you call this list extraction function,

```
...
int asd[capacity];
int count = list_extract_ints(message.mesg_text, asd, capacity);
```